# Decoding UTF-8 String, then encoding it in 8859-2 for Slovakian alphabet

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to translate strings into Slovakian alphabet (8859-2 encoding)
via a matching table I created.
Problem is some characters do not actually change and the output string shows me "?" for some slovakian character.

How do I do that? 
I did something like this first :

```
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("buffer", ".tmp");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);
        Reader fr = new FileReader(fileOriginal);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while (br.ready()) {
            fw.write(br.readLine().replace("#/e#" , "ě").replace("#>E#" , "É")
        }
```

but some Characters are not correctly replaced.

For example, in this String : "allo #>e# de #>E#" (just an example), 
it should give me "allo ě de É" but it gives me "allo ? de ?" because UTF-8 doesn't recognize these characters.
What do I need to do for my java program to recognize it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can certainly represent "É", etc., in UTF-8 -- I'm not sure you have identified the real problem here. Manipulating the way text is encoded by fiddling with String objects is usually doomed to failure, because the internal encoding of a String is opaque. If you need to do low-level encoding fiddling, you'll need to work with byte lists. But I would expect that what you need can be done using Java's built-in text codecs -- or do you have reason to think otherwise? What encoding is used in your input file? What encoding do you need for the output?

Comment: I'm actually not working with encoding and bytes.
I just want .txt file I give as a parameter with characters to get replaced with some characters like ě and É but it doesn't work and it shows me "?" .

Comment: OK; then I don't really understand why you mention UTF-8: nothing in the code sample you posted seems specific to UTF-8. What encoding does the input use, and what encoding do you want for the output? What steps are you taking to ensure that these encodings are respected?

Comment: Create an InputStreamReader with the UTF8 charset and read your text with that. Create an OutputStreamWriter with the ISO-8859-2 charset and write your text with that. You don't need to replace anything in the text. You're not specifying any charset anywhere in your code, and are thus reading and writing everything with your platform default charset.

Comment: I think you need to divide and conquer. There are three stages: reading the text using its character encoding, translating the # escapes (unfamiliar to me but you have a couple of examples), writing the output to a text file using your desired encoding (8859-2). Which one is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this should works for you?

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fr,"UTF-8"));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fw,"8859-2"));
while (br.ready()) {
    bw.write(br.readLine());
}
```

This code reads a file content encoded in UTF-8 and writes by encoding in 8859-2.

Comment: This is not what I want, I don't have access to the original file with slovenian characters.
I have access to a file with characters like this #/A#  and #>e# because they weren't correctly translated to UTF-8 or 16 I don't know.(western Europe).
So now I have a file incorrectly translated and I want to rechange these characters in "ě" for #>e# in the file for example. 
#>e# isn't actually a real character so I need to provide a table in my program which I did.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. Verify your source code java encoding (the .java), it must be UTF-8. if not, the compiler will "lost" your special characters. Force the output in UTF-8 too. On my computer, I've done a test, your conversion works.

Comment: Strange. From where you execute your code ? (windows shell, linux, eclipse ?) If the console is not in UTF-8, the output won't be correct.

Comment: Windows console. Nvm my last comment, in the console of Eclipse it works. Character É is shown.
But if I do a System.out.println("É"), simple as that, it will show "?" in Windows console.
Same when I'm replacing character in files. É will be shown as "?".

Comment: The windows console is not UTF-8 , it's ANSI (Windows-1252)

Comment: The eclipse console is UTF-8

Comment: Ah ok, and what about files ? 
replacing characters in a file with FileWriter as shown in my 1st post also show me "?" in the file created.

Comment: The ě cannot be represented in ANSI so in windows console, it'll be never correct

Comment: 1) The source code contening the conversion characters must be in UTF-8 2) You have explicitly to precise the output encoding to UTF-8 in your file writer by using an OutputStreamWriter (see my sample)

Comment: (and view the result file in a UTF-8 compliance editor like Notepad++)