# How to download String file which contain special characters of slovenia

Tags: android, android-networking

I am trying to download the `json` file which contains slovenian characters,While downloading `json` file as a string I am getting special character as specified below in json data

```
"send_mail": "Po�lji elektronsko sporocilo.",
"str_comments_likes": "Komentarji, v�ecki in mejniki",
```

Code which I am using

```
URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
conection.connect();
try {
    InputStream input1 = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 300);
    String myData = "";
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input1));
    StringBuilder totalValue = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        totalValue.append(line).append('\n');
    }
    input1.close();
    String value = totalValue.toString();
    Log.v("To Check Problem from http paramers", value);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.v("Exception Character Isssue", "" + e.getMessage());
}
```

I want to know how to get characters downloaded properly.

Comment: have a look at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737554/issue-while-downloading-file-with-special-character) if you haven't already .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decoding UTF-8 String, then encoding it in 8859-2 for Slovakian alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521867/decoding-utf-8-string-then-encoding-it-in-8859-2-for-slovakian-alphabet)

Comment: I tried changing to UTF-8 or 8859-2 ,nothing works,only change what i see is 8859-2 character changes from � to [] .

Comment: I'm confused- where is the actual JSON? You're not using any Android or Java JSON library

Comment: @Rakesh r u using retrofit library ??

Comment: I am not using retrofit library and i updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this way which worked for me

```
InputStream input1 = new BufferedInputStream(conection.getInputStream(), 300);

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input1, "Windows-1252"));
```

I figured out by this `windows-1252`, by putting json file in asset folder of the android application folder, where it showed same special characters like specified above,there it showed auto suggestion options to change encoding to `UTF-8`,`ISO-8859-1`,`ASCII` and `Windows-1252`, So I changed to `windows-1252`, which worked in android studio which i replicated the same in our code, which worked.

Answer (score 4):

You need to encode string bytes to UTF-8. Please check following code :

```
String slovenianJSON = new String(value.getBytes([Original Code]),"utf-8");
JSONObject newJSON = new JSONObject(reconstitutedJSONString);
String javaStringValue = newJSON.getString("content");
```

I hope it will help you!

Answer (score 2):

Decoding line in while loop can work. Also you should add your connection in `try catch` block in case of `IOException`

```
URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
try {
    URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
    conection.connect();
    InputStream input1 = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 300);
    String myData = "";
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input1));
    StringBuilder totalValue = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        line = URLEncoder.encode(line, "UTF8");
        totalValue.append(line).append('\n');
    }
    input1.close();
    String value = totalValue.toString();
    Log.v("To Check Problem from http paramers", value);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.v("Exception Character Isssue", "" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear why you're not using Android's JSONObject class (and related classes). You can try this, however:

```
String str = new String(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

But you really should use the JSON libraries rather than parsing yourself

Answer (score 1):

When creating the InputStreamReader at this line:

```
       BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input1));
```

send the charset to the constructor like this:

```
       BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input1), Charset.forName("UTF_8"));
```

Answer (score 1):

problem is in character set
as per Wikipedia Slovene alphabet supported by UTF-8,UTF-16, ISO/IEC 8859-2 (Latin-2). find which character set used in server, and use the same character set for encoding.
if it is UTF-8 encode like this

```
       BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), Charset.forName("UTF_8"));
```

if you had deffrent character set use that.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue because of the swedish characters.

So i have used BufferedReader to resolved this issue. I have converted the Response using StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 and use that response. Please find my answer as below.

```
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.body().byteStream(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        total.append(line).append('\n');
    }
```

and use this `total.toString()` and assigned this response to my class.

I have used Retrofit for calling web service.